Do I need a heat spreader for the Samsung 990 Pro in a Lenovo Thinkpad P16 Gen2?
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P16 Gen2 that has 1TB SSD installed.
However I want to upgrade it to two times 2TB using two Samsung 990 Pro SSD.
As the space in a laptop is quite small, I did not order a model with extra "heat spreader", but I wonder:
Will it be OK to use that SSD without heat spreader in that laptop?
Crucial, claiming to have compatible SSDs, seems to use some thin black heat spreader (that's what the photo suggests to me) for the Crucial T500 2TB PCIe Gen4 NVMe M.2 SSD, however (I picked the Samsung, because it was less expensive).
Crucial also offers a version with a (thicker?) heatsink, but it's not obvious from the photo how thick that heat sink really is.
OTOH Lenovo does not specify, because they assume, you buy the SSDs directly from Lenovo (at a higher price).

This might better be asked at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Samsung 990 Pro SSD is a PciEx 4.0 SSD. Usually such models don't get so hot that a heat spreader is required.

This ^^· That doesn't mean an heatsink isn't helpful in certain circumstances.

As I had installed two modules, I can provide a kind of answer:
There are two slots: One below the keyboard, and one more easily accessible from the bottom.

The slot below the keyboard featured "some larger black plastic block" of unknown purpose. Maybe it's there to prevent vibration of the module, maybe it's there to avoid static electricity, or maybe it's there to spread the heat. The pre-installed module had a tight contact to that block, and therefore it made it rather hard to slide the module out from the socket.

The slot on the bottom features a copper-colored cover (with some "isolation strip" inside), so I guess it shields electromagnetic radiation, And if that "isolation strip" has contact with the SSD module, it may spread the heat a bit.



Running Linux (openSUSE Leap 15.6) it showed the temperature being around 44°C (AFAIK Samsung specified temperatures up to 90°C).
However as I know, SSDs heat up significantly when writing, so that may not be a number that covers all use cases.
So to summarize:
It seems you don't need a separate heat spreader for the SSD modules, and maybe there isn't even room for such.
